# Word toc show levels adjustment using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, tableofcontents

I'm fairly new to VBA in general, but currently I'm working on publishing a document utilizing IBM's Rational Publishing Engine which publishes a document out of DOORS (Dynamic Object Oriented Requirements System).  After publishing there are a series of macros that are utilized to expandOLEs, merge paragraphs, centerFigures, etc.  I'm looking to add a macro that will adjust my table of contents to only show levels 2.  I was thinking something like the below would work, but have not had much success.

```
Sub Tocadjust()

    Dim toc As TableOfContents
    Dim tocEntry As Field
    
    Set toc = ActiveDocument.TableOfContents(1)
    For Each tocEntry In toc.Range.Fields
        tocEntry.Select
        toc.UpperHeadingLevel = 1
        toc.LowerHeadingLevel = 2
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Tables of Contents in Word are, themselves, fields.

They do not, generally, contain fields. They do have switches.

Running the following code adds a switch limiting the TOC to levels 1 and 2.

```
Sub TocAdjust()
    ' Charles Kenyon
    ' Limit first TOC to levels 1 and 2
    '
    ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).LowerHeadingLevel = 2
    ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).UpperHeadingLevel = 1
End Sub
```

This will throw an error if there is no Table of Contents field. Note that Tables of Figures also use the TOC field.

Here is what a TOC field looks like before and after running the macro.

[image: screenshot of fields]

Your code was trying to act on "entries" rather than on the field in general.

Comment: Thank you sir.  Unfortunately this was unable to fix my issue, but I was able to fix it by adjusting the TOC code value on the front matter template in my Rational Publishing Engine Template ({ TOC \o "1-2" \h \z \t "Heading ,1,3,4,Attachment,1,Appendix 1,1,Revision Record,3" })